# Declaring variable with same name but different type

Tags: c++, c, global-variables

I am trying to make something with supports IPV4 or IPV6.
The code is similar for these two so I tried something like this.
Since the only difference in code later on depends on this sin variable how can I compile just one of them. Lets suppose "ipv" variable in IF statement is true or false depends on user input

```
//FOR IPV4
//struct sockaddr_in sin;
//FOR IPV6
//struct sockaddr_in6 sin;
//IPV4


// IPV4 ---------------------------------------
if (ipv){
  struct sockaddr_in sin;   
  if ( (s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) < 0) { 
    perror("Chyba pri vytvareni socketu");  
    return -1;
  }


  sin.sin_family = AF_INET;     
  sin.sin_port = htons(port_number);
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;
}

// IPV6 ---------------------------------------
else{

  struct sockaddr_in6 sin;
  if ( (s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) < 0) { 
    perror("Chyba pri vytvareni socketu");  
    return -1;
  }

  sin.sin6_family = AF_INET6;     
  sin.sin6_port = htons(port_number);
  sin.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
  sin.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
}   

if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin) ) < 0 ) {
    printf("error on bind\n"); return -1;  
}

if (listen(s, 5)) { 
    printf ("error on listen\n"); 
return -1;
}

sinlen = sizeof(sin);
pid_t pid;

while (1) {


    /* accepting new connection request from client,
    socket id for the new connection is returned in t */
    if ( (t = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, &sinlen) ) < 0 ) {
      printf("error on accept\n");  /* accept error */
      return -1;
    }
continues .... not important
```

this code will give me:

```
server.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:  
server.cpp:132:35: error: ‘sin’ was not declared in this scope
   if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin) ) < 0 ) {
                               ^
server.cpp:145:19: error: ‘sin’ was not declared in this scope
   sinlen = sizeof(sin);
               ^
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

So question is how can I make this done without writing the same code twice with different "sin";

Comment: Change your variable name.  The name `sin` conflicts with the `sin` (trigonometry) function in the math library.

Comment: Make variable `sockaddr sin` before `if`'s and initialize it in the enc of each `if` with your local `sin`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no, it is not.

Comment: @Status well its is sockaddr_in or sockaddr_in6 which is difference ... please post a code since I dont really understand what you mean :)

Comment: If you use the `getaddrinfo()`-API in POSIX, you don't have to worry about this detail, because it will automatically allocate the right address.

Comment: @Denis but you are using it as if it has 'sockaddr' type: `(struct sockaddr *) &sin`. So what's the difference?

Comment: @Status If I put:
struct sockaddr_in sin before at top it will work only for IPV4 
and struct sockaddr_in6 sin only for IPV6 I think I am missing something can you please post a code how would you do it?

Comment: @Denis - Is `ipv` determined at runtime by the user as you have mentioned or is `ipv` decided at compile time (using a `#define` maybe) as you seem to desire ("can I compile just one of them")?

Comment: @Denis put ANOTHER variable with the type of `sockaddr` before if's and assign desired local `sin` inside your if's

Comment: @Satus like:
struct sockaddr sin; // before if 
struct sockaddr_in sin; // inside if 
struct sonaddr_in6 sin; // inside else
??

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this by using sockaddr_storage and its working well

```
struct sockaddr_storage sin;
struct sockaddr_in *sin4;
struct sockaddr_in *sin6;
// IPV4 ---------------------------------------
if (ipv == true){
    sin4 = (struct sockaddr_in*)&sin;   
    if ( (s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) < 0) { 
         perror("Chyba pri vytvareni socketu");  
         return -1;
    }


    sin4->sin_family = AF_INET;     
    sin4->sin_port = htons(port_number);
    sin4->sin_addr.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;
}

// IPV6 ---------------------------------------
else{

    sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6*)&sin;
    if ( (s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) < 0) { 
        perror("Chyba pri vytvareni socketu");  
        return -1;
    }

    sin6->sin6_family = AF_INET6;     
    sin6->sin6_port = htons(port_number);
    sin6->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    sin6->sin6_flowinfo = 0;
}   

if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin) ) < 0 ) {
    printf("error on bind\n"); return -1;  
}

if (listen(s, 5)) { 
    printf ("error on listen\n"); 
    return -1;
}

sinlen = sizeof(sin);
pid_t pid;

while (1) {


     /* accepting new connection request from client,
     socket id for the new connection is returned in t */
     if ( (t = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, &sinlen) ) < 0 ) {
         printf("error on accept\n");  /* accept error */
     return -1;
     }
     continues .... not important
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a typical case when you might use a *union*.

```
typedef union {
    struct sockaddr_in v4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 v6;
} sockaddr_union;

sockaddr_union sin;
```

Then, when you know you're working with IPV4, use sin.v4 in place of sin, and when you know you're working with IPV6, use sin.v6

Comment: Don't call it `sockaddr_un`.  That's the name of the struct used for UNIX domain sockets.